# Left join using java stream on two lists

Tags: java, java-8

[the rest descritpion of tthe main class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDMBw.png)[here is the image for the class description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzWnC.png)I have an entity Customers with cid,cname and aid and another entity Address with aid, city and state.

I have taken data of both the entities in two different lists -list and list . i want a result list (left join on both customer and address)that contains data from both the lists using java stream api or any other feature of java 8. and further what should be the type of result list.?

is it possible to do so.?

please help.

Thanks in advance.

---

public class Customers {

```
private Integer cid;
private String name;
private Integer aid;
// getters and setters
// tostring()
// constructors with and without params
```

public class Address {

```
private Integer aid;
private String city;
private String state;
private Integer pincode;
//getters and setters
//tostring()
//constructors with and without params
```

public class Cust_Add_DTO {

```
private Integer cid;
private String name;
private Integer aid;
private String city;
private String state;
private Integer pincode;
// getters and setters
// tostring()
// constructors with and without params
```

public class DemoMain {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Customers> customers = new ArrayList<Customers>();
    List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<Address>();
    customers.add(new Customers(1, "abc1", 123));
    customers.add(new Customers(2, "abc2", 124));
    customers.add(new Customers(3, "abc3", 125));
    customers.add(new Customers(4, "abc4", 126));
    customers.add(new Customers(5, "abc5", 127));

    addresses.add(new Address(123, "bangalore", "karnataka", 101010));
    addresses.add(new Address(125, "chennai", "tamil nadu", 202020));
    addresses.add(new Address(127, "hyderabad", "telanagana", 303030));

    List<Cust_Add_DTO> mergerdleftjoin = customers.stream()
            .flatMap(x -> addresses.stream().filter(y -> x.getAid().equals(y.getAid())))
            .map(y -> new Cust_Add_DTO(x.getCid(), y.getAid(), y.getCity(), y.getPincode(), y.getState(),
                    x.getName()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: yes, you would have to give it a try. result type should be something that you desire as an output.

Comment: Share the class details and what you have tried so far as said by Naman.

Comment: Please don't post code as an image. It makes it difficult to search and people can't copy the code from your question to their answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see that you have a list of two entities from DB:

```
// @Entity
class Customers {

    private int cid;
    private String name;
    private int aid;
}

// @Entity
class Address {

    private int aid;
    private String city;
    private String state;
}
```

It's better to split DAO layer entities from DTO; so you should create required DTO:

```
class CustomerDTO {

    private int cid;
    private String name;
    private AddressDTO address;
}

class AddressDTO {

    private int aid;
    private String city;
    private String state;
}
```

Right now you are ready to write a `leftJoin` method using `Streams`:

```
public static List<CustomerDTO> leftJoin(List<Customers> customers, List<Address> addresses) {
    Map<Integer, Address> aidAddress = addresses.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Address::getAid, Function.identity()));

    return customers.stream()
                    .map(customer -> {
                        CustomerDTO customerDto = new CustomerDTO();
                        // set all fields from customer -> customerDto

                        Address address = aidAddress.get(customer.getAid());

                        if (address != null) {
                            AddressDTO addressDto = new AddressDTO();
                            // set all fields from address -> addressDto
                            customerDto.setAddress(addressDto);
                        }

                        return customerDto;
                    })
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: Sir suppose one aid in Customer is associated to many aid in Address and assuming  that aid is not the identity column in Address but aid is identity column in Customer . then how can the problem be solved . I am getting duplicate key as an exception in thread main . please provide any solution . Thanks in advance.